# Does Ethereum Wallet not sync ERC-20 tokens in light mode?

Tags: wallets, tokens, erc-20, light-clients

As of `0.9.1` Ethereum Wallet rolled out a "sync with light client (beta)" functionality. However, on my machine it does not seem to update `ERC-20` token values, only `eth` count.

Is that the actual case? Does this feature not yet support synchronization of tokens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The light sync feature does support `ERC-20` tokens (tested with `0.9.2`). In order to track them you'll have to manually add each token contract. Just go to the `CONTRACT`'s tab and click `WATCH TOKEN` on the `CUSTOM TOKENS` section.